# How to integrate google calendar in my website?

Tags: javascript, python, django, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to access and show the google calendar of any user (after login) in my website using django. User can change the calendar from the website and it should be visible in google calendar.
I dont want to make user calendar public. ([Ref](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar))

This is what I did.

```
def connect_google_api():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json')
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials2.json',SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        
        with open('token.json','w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    
    service = build('calendar','v3',credentials=creds)

    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()+'Z'
    
    page_token = None
    calendar_ids = []
    while True:
        calendar_list = service.calendarList().list(pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for calendar_list_entry in calendar_list['items']:
            print(calendar_list_entry['id'])
            if "myorganization" in calendar_list_entry['id']:
                # print(calendar_list_entry['id'])
                calendar_ids.append(calendar_list_entry['id'])
        page_token = calendar_list.get('nextPageToken')
        if not page_token:
            break
    
    print(calendar_ids)

    for calendar_id in calendar_ids:
        count = 0
        print(calendar_id)
        eventsResult = service.events().list(
            calendarId = calendar_id,
            timeMin = now,
            maxResults = 5,
            singleEvents = True,
            orderBy = 'startTime').execute()
        events = eventsResult.get('items',[])
        # return calendar_ids,events
        response = JsonResponse(events,safe=False)
        # print(eventsResult)
        
        if not events:
            print('No upcoming events found')
        # print(events)
        print("-----------------------------------")
```

I am able to get all the events of user's calendar. Now I want to show this calendar to the user.
I trying to show these events using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/).

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var day = currentDate.getDate();
      var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
      var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
      current_date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
      console.log(currentDate);
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        initialDate: currentDate,
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        events: [
          {

          },

        ]
      });

      calendar.render();
    });
```

events which I have is in this format which is not working in FullCalendar. I want suggestion on showing google calendar in my website using this events which may or may not include FullCalendar.

events:

```
{
    'kind': 'calendar#event',
    'etag': '"1234567"',
    'id': '5c3b0081234567Z',
    'status': 'confirmed',
    'htmlLink': 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=123456',
    'created': 'datetime',
    'updated': 'datetime',
    'summary': 'Meetings',
    'creator': {
        'email': 'somemail@gmail.com'
    },
    'organizer': {
        'email': 'somemail@gmail.com'
    },
    'start': {
        'dateTime': 'datetime',
        'timeZone': 'timezone'
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': 'datetime',
        'timeZone': 'timezone'
    },
    'recurringEventId': 'oidsvnsodincso',
    'originalStartTime': {
        'dateTime': 'date time',
        'timeZone': 'timezone'
    },
    'iCalUID': 'soivnvndifuvn@google.com',
    'sequence': 0,
    'attendees': [{
        'email': 'somemail@gmail.com',
        'organizer': True,
        'responseStatus': 'accepted'
    }, {
        'email': 'mymail@gmail.com',
        'self': True,
        'responseStatus': 'needsAction'
    }],
    'hangoutLink': 'somelink',
    'conferenceData': {
        'createRequest': {
            'requestId': 'odivnodvinsodn',
            'conferenceSolutionKey': {
                'type': 'hangoutsMeet'
            },
            'status': {
                'statusCode': 'success'
            }
        },
        'entryPoints': [{
            'entryPointType': 'video',
            'uri': 'somelink',
            'label': 'somelabel'
        }, {
            'entryPointType': 'more',
            'uri': 'https://somelink',
            'pin': '1234567'
        }, {
            'regionCode': 'CountryCode',
            'entryPointType': 'phone',
            'uri': 'tel:+1234567',
            'label': '+1234567',
            'pin': '1234567'
        }],
        'conferenceSolution': {
            'key': {
                'type': 'hangoutsMeet'
            },
            'name': 'Google Meet',
            'iconUri': 'https://somefont.png'
        },
        'conferenceId': 'iodviduv',
        'signature': 'sivbuvbdufv'
    },
    'reminders': {
        'useDefault': True
    },
    'eventType': 'default'
}
```

Comment: `events which I have is in this format which is not working in FullCalendar`...you need to translate the data into the format which fullCalendar accepts. You will need to write your own code to do that, either in python or JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible.  The google calendar API will give you programmatic access to the data behind the Google calendar website.  The response is returned in JSon. You will need to format the display of this yourself.

If the calendar in question is stored on Google Workspace then you could use a service account to access it again just the data.  The display will still need to be handled by you as service accounts again only allow for programmatic access to the data.

If you want someone to be able to view the calendar in the google calendar web application then the calendar will need to be public or you will need to grant them access to it.  If the calendar is just set to public then they will have read only access they wont be able to change anything.